# Hitting time of open set for adapted cadlag process is stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Variants of this question have been asked many times (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165471/adapted-cadlag-processes-hitting-times-are-stopping-times)) but none of them touch on a particular step. I will first state the theorem and proof (from Protter's *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*} and then my attempt afterwards.

**Theorem statement:**
Let $X_t$ be a adapted cadlag process and let $\Lambda$ be an open set. Then the hitting time, T, of $\Lambda$ for $X_t$ is a stopping time.

> **Proof from Protter:** It suffices to show $\{T<t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$, $0 \leq t \leq \infty$. We have,
> \begin{equation} \{T < t\} = \bigcup_{s\in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, t)} \{X_s \in \Lambda\}. \end{equation} Then, $\{X_s \in \Lambda\} = X_s^{-1}(\Lambda) \in \mathcal{F}_s$ since $X_s$ is measurable and $\Lambda$ is open. Hence,
> $\{T < t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and since $t$ was arbitrary the result
> follows.

Now, the part I do not completely follow is the equality:
\begin{equation} \{T < t\} = \bigcup_{s\in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, t)} \{X_s \in \Lambda\}. \end{equation}
So I have tried to fill in the gaps, here is my proof of the above equality:

> First,
>
> \begin{equation} \{\omega:T(\omega)<t\} = \{\omega: \exists s<t \text{ such that } X_s(\omega) \in \Lambda\} =\bigcup_{s\in [0, t)} \{ \omega: X_s(\omega) \in \Lambda\}. \end{equation}
> So it suffices to
> show equality of $A :=\bigcup_{s\in [0, t)} \{ X_s \in \Lambda\}$ and
> $B:=\bigcup_{s\in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, t)} \{X_s \in \Lambda\}$.
> Clearly $B \subset A$. To show $A \subset B$, take $\omega \in A$.
> Then $\exists s<t$ with $X_s(\omega) \in \Lambda$ (and we assume $s \not\in \mathbb{Q}$).
> Then there exists a sequence $\{s_n\}$ such that $s_n \searrow s$ through $\mathbb{Q}$. This implies, by right
> continuity of paths of $X_t$, that \begin{equation} X_s(\omega) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_{s_n}(\omega) \end{equation}
> Since
> $\Lambda$ is open and $X_s(\omega) \in \Lambda$, then $s_N \in \mathbb{Q}$, $s_N < t$ can be chosen with $X_{s_N}(\omega) \in \Lambda$. This implies $\omega \in B$ and we are done.

Is my attempt at filling in the gaps correct?